# Why Servlet.getContext(String) does not return null after undeploy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat10

I am using `tomcat-10`(jakarta). According [to the doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationContextFacade.html#getContext(java.lang.String))
`getContext(String)` return `null` if context not exists or restricted access. But in practice is not correct. For example I have two web application with `/app1` and `/app2`. After running I undeploy `/app2`. I also checked registered `MBeans` with JMX and there is no registered servlet with context `/app2`. But when I call `getContext(/app2)` it returns `ROOT` `servlet`. Is it a bug or works normally?

**UPDATE**
For testing I just remove tomcat default `ROOT` web application. After removing when I call `getContext` method I got `null` if the requested context not exists. So that I think there is some missing information on the documentation or the custom implementation of `Servlet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to [`ServletContext#getContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontext#getContext-java.lang.String-) does not need to point to the exact URI of the context. Therefore:

- all strings that **start** with `/app1` will give you the context for the `/app1` application,
- all strings that **start** with `/app2` will give you the context for the `/app2` application,
- after you stop `/app2`, all requests for `/app2` will be routed to the `ROOT` context. Therefore `getContext("/app2")` will return the `ROOT` context.

Comment: P.Karwasz thanks for detailed answer. I removed `ROOT` context then whenever I call `getContext("/app2")` it returns `null`. But if `ROOT` context exists then `getContext` return `ROOT` as you wrote. Maybe I misunderstood the documentation or maybe was not clarified this situation

Answer (score 0):

The getContext method is to get the reference to servlet context for different web applications and will not null if your current application does have permission to access other contexts as specified by the defaults of tomcat i.e. cross-context = true.

Also, your current web app already has a reference to the servlet context may be in your application variable

Comment: but documentation said that `the ServletContext object that corresponds to the named URL, or null if either none exists or the container wishes to restrict this access.` in this case it should return `null` if context not exists

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).